# How can I make MacOS always show the Bluetooth icon in the top bar even when it's turned off?

Tags: macos, bluetooth, menu-bar, ventura

I already have this setting:

[image: Control Center]

I like to toggle it on/off frequently, and I'd like to be able to do that from the top menu bar instead of going into System Settings.

Updates in response to comments:

MBP 16-inch 2019

[image: Display resolution]
[image: top bar]

It seems to be working today! (It's visible!)

Comment: What version of MacOS Ventura are you running? I'm running 13.0 and it is still in the menu bar even when it's off. I have bluetooth on "Show in Menu Bar". Maybe try an update.

Comment: What is your Mac by year and model? What is the size and resolution of the display you are using with your Mac, if not the built-in MacBook display? How many icons are typically active in the top right portion of your menu bar? Does this issue arise even if there are no apps open (some apps occupy a really large portion of the menu bar when open and active)? Can u pls update your question accordingly?

Comment: @Alper As I was updating my question, I noticed that it's working today!

Comment: @cashiecoder Last night, I did restart my Mac due to a pending MacOS security update. I don't know if it makes sense that the update (or the restart) could have solved it. But it seems solved. Thanks.

Comment: @Alper That's thoughtful. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

In macOS Ventura and Sonoma you need to drag it to the Menu Bar from Control Center.

From the Apple Docs:

1. [Drag from Control Center](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/quickly-change-settings-mchl50f94f8f/mac#:%7E:text=Tip%3A%20If%20you%20often%20use%20an%20item%2C%20you%20can%20drag%20it%20from%20Control%20Center%20to%20the%20menu%20bar%2C%20to%20keep%20it%20handy%20there.%20To%20remove%20the%20item%20from%20the%20menu%20bar%2C%20press%20and%20hold%20the%20Command%20key%20while%20you%20drag%20the%20item%20out%20of%20the%20menu%20bar.).
2. [Arrange icons in Menu Bar](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/whats-in-the-menu-bar-mchlp1446/mac#:%7E:text=To%20rearrange%20status%20menus%2C%20press%20and%20hold%20the%20Command%20key%20while%20you%20drag%20an%20icon.%20To%20quickly%20remove%20a%20status%20menu%2C%20press%20and%20hold%20the%20Command%20key%20while%20you%20drag%20the%20icon%20out%20of%20the%20menu%20bar.).

Comment: No as the OP does have it set to menu and it does appear in menu bar but only sometimes.

Comment: Setting, "show in Menu Bar" to Bluetooth does nothing in Sonoma. It might be a bug/situation where you need to do both.

Comment: I'm not sure how that setting even allowed intermittent display of the Bluetooth icon in the menu bar. For me, I applied the same setting but got no effect until I dragged it from Control Center.

Comment: I don't know if your answer is correct or will help anyone, but I appreciate the effort, so +1. My computer still seems to be doing fine: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/462084/53510

Answer (score 0):

Last night, I needed to restart my Mac due to a pending MacOS security update.

I don't know if it makes sense that the update (or the restart) could have solved it.

But it seems solved; today I can see the Bluetooth icon even when it's turned off.

Comment: The reappearing of the Bluetooth icon when off might be temporary in your case because there seems to be quite a few icons on the top right of your menu bar. It is possible that the Bluetooth icon is being hidden by macOS at times, especially when you activate an app with many top menu items. You may need to reduce the number of icons appearing on the top right of the menu bar or use a third-party app that manages the icons on the top-right of the menu bar.

Comment: @Alper  I hope it stays there!